# Why the output of the ffmpeg-python doesn't match the image shape?

Tags: python, image, video, ffmpeg

I used the `ffmpeg-python` module to convert video to images. Specifically, I used the code provided by the official git repo of `ffmpeg-python`, as below

```
out, _ = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(in_filename)
    .filter('select', 'gte(n,{})'.format(frame_num))
    .output('pipe:', vframes=1, format='image2', vcodec='mjpeg')
    .run(capture_stdout=True)
)
im = np.frombuffer(out, 'uint8')
print(im.shape[0]/3/1080)
# 924.907098765432
```

The original video is of size (1920, 1080) and pix_fmt 'yuv420p', but the outputs of the above code is not 1920.

I have figured out by myself that the output of ffmpeg.run() is not a decoded image array, but a byte string encoded by JPEG format. To restore the image into a numpy array, simply use the cv2.imdecode() function. For example,

```
im = cv2.imdecode(im, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

However, I can't use `opencv` on my embeded Linux system. So my question now is that, can I get numpy output from `ffmpeg-python` directly, without the need of converting it by opencv?

Comment: Share full ffmpeg log.

Comment: Updated in the description.

Answer (score 0):

To make `ffmpeg-python` ouput raw image array directly, use the following command:

```py
out, _ = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(in_filename)
    .filter('select', 'gte(n,{})'.format(frame_num))
    .output('pipe:', vframes=1, format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
    .run(capture_stdout=True)
)
im = np.frombuffer(out, 'uint8')
```